# Can we pass Session Information in <img src="Session.info"> file in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

This is an Registration Form in MVC. I have used string as an storage in Database(eg: imgpath varchar(256))and Upload the image in img folder of SOURCE folder(eg: ~/img/img_name.jpeg).After logging in I pass this information as Session Variable and use that in img src? But it cannot render the image any suggestions?

```
<img src="@Html.ViewData["Img"]" alt="IMG" height="250" width="250">
<img src="@HTMLContext.Current.Session["Profile_pic"]" alt="IMG" height="250" width="250">
```

CSHTML//

```
    @if (Session["email"] != null)
    {
        <h1>Welcome @Session["email"].ToString()</h1>

        <br /><br />

        <img src="@Html.ViewData["Img"]" alt="img" height="150" width="150" />


    }
```

WelcomeController//

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string s = (string)Session["Profile_pic"];

        ViewData["Img"] = s;
        return View();
    }
```

LoginController()//

```
    using (DemoEntities db = new DemoEntities())
    {               
        if (userdetail == null)
        {
            user.LoginErrorMsg = "Invalid Username or Password";
            return View("Index", user);
        }
        else
        {
            Session["email"] = user.Email;
            Session["Profile_Pic"] = user.User_image;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "FirstView");
        }
```

Comment: Please check your `Session` variable stored data or not, when you are login?

Comment: What gets rendered when you run the code?